# If a function has a non-vanishing derivative on an interval, show that it is one-to-one

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives

Let $f$ be differentiable on an interval $A$. If $f'(x)\neq 0$ on $A$, show that $f$ is injective (one-to-one) on $A$.

Is the converse true? Provide an example to show that the converse statement need not be true.

I don't know where to start. Should I use IVT somehow?

Comment: Hints: (1) $f'$ has the intermediate value (Darboux) property, (2) mean value theorem.

Comment: I still don't see it. Can you give me some more detailed proof/help?

Answer (score 1):

Let $x,y\in A$, $x\ne y$. Suppose $x<y$. The function $t\mapsto f(t)$ is differentiable on $(x,y)$ by the assumption. So, there is a $c\in (x,y)$ such that $f(y)-f(x)=f'(c)(y-x)\ne 0$, which implies $f(x)\ne f(y)$. So, $f$ is one-to-one.

Answer (score 1):

Proof sketch based on my comment above:

First, note that differentiability of $f$ everywhere in $A$ does not imply that the derivative $f'$ is continuous. However, it does imply that $f'$ has the intermediate value property (also called the [Darboux property](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Darboux%27s_theorem_(analysis))). What this means is that if $x,y \in A$, with $f'(x) < f'(y)$, then given any $c$ between $f'(x)$ and $f'(y)$, there is some $z$ between $x$ and $y$ such that $f'(z) = c$.

From this fact, we can conclude that either $f'(x) > 0$ everywhere in $A$, or $f'(x) < 0$ everywhere in $A$. If this were not the case, then we would have $f'(x) > 0$ and $f'(y) < 0$ for some $x,y \in A$, hence there would be some $z$ with $f'(z) = 0$.

Without loss of generality, assume that $f'(x) > 0$ everywhere in $A$.

Now let $x,y \in A$ with $x<y$. By the mean value theorem, there is some $z$ such that $x<y<z$ and
$$f'(z) = \frac{f(y)-f(x)}{y-x}$$

From this, conclude that not only is $f$ one-to-one, in fact it is strictly monotone.

Comment: How about the converse?

Comment: @user296855: How about $f(x) = x^3$?